# How to categorize a list of hashtags into certain categories in excel using formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have excel data having hashtags with underscore only:

```
#programming_contest 
#basics_of_cs 
#competitive_programming
#contest_programming 
#scholarship 
#blog_post 
#inspiration
```

... and so on.

I need to categorize all the hashtags in a fixed number of categories based on the types of words they contain. Such as, for the above set of hashtags, these are three categories I am planning, "TECHNICAL", "EDUCATION", "OTHERS". Hashtags containing words like programming, cs etc. will come under this "TECHNICAL" tag. All other hashtags other than "TECHNICAL" & "EDUCATION" will be put under the "OTHERS" category.

This is how it looks:

```
"TECHNICAL" = #programming_contest ,#basics_of_cs ,#competitive_programming, #contest_programming 
"EDUCATION" = #scholarship 
"OTHERS" = #blog_post, #ispiration
```

**Is there any way I can do this in excel using formula?**

Comment: With enough cpu cores, ram and time, virtually anything is possible.

Comment: look at the q&a's in the [tag:textjoin] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Excel Table called HashMap:
[image]

Assuming your data starts in A2 like so:
[image]

Then use this formula in B2 downward:

`=INDEX(HashMap,MATCH(A2,HashMap[Hashtag],0),2)`